# Django - unable to modify a record

Tags: python, django, forms, view

Hy. I want to modify a record for my database.
I have:

models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
email = models.EmailField(blank = True)
grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class PeopleForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = People 

    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'grade']
```

views.py

```
def modify(request, person_pk):
title = 'Creating new program'
template = 'modify.html'

data = People.objects.get(pk = person_pk)

form = PeopleForm(instance=data)
context = {'form': form}
if request.POST:
    form = PeopleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/peoples/'))
    else:
        return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^modify/(?P<person_pk>.*)$', views.modify, name='modify'),
```

forms.py

```
class PeopleForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = People 
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'grade')
```

And template

```
<form action="/peoples/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_ul}}
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify">
</form>
```

I don't know why when I click the modify button, I complete the fields and when I press the button to the previous page, the entry field from database doesn't update. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I see that looks odd is that your HTML `form` tag has `"/peoples/"` as its action, but that URL is not bound to your form processing view in the code we see here. I mostly use `action=""` in my forms, so that it submits to the same URL that rendered the view.

Secondly, when you redefine your python variable `form` in your view:

```
if request.POST:
    form = PeopleForm(request.POST)
```

You have already assigned the old `form` to the context, and do not reassign it. So if your form is not valid, you won't see the errors or submitted values.

This is of course irrelevant if your form action is wrong such that the view is not called with the `POST` data.

Comment: If I'm deleting "/peoples/" from HTML form tag then it will create a new record instead of modifying the existing one.

Comment: Try passing in `instance` to your form constructor along with the `POST` data: `form = PeopleForm(request.POST, instance=data)`